# Images placed with .append() / .load() not taking on the styles they should be

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website has a few sort of "display containers", into which content is loaded using `.load()`, depending on which item is selected. These display containers can be a few different states, depending on wether your viewing on a mobile device etc, such as all the containers having word spacing to give the images in them a bit of breathing room, or setting the content to justify.

Now, if I include the images in these containers from the start—that is to say, they are part of the initial DOM—everything shows up fine. The images will be spaced apart using `word-spacing` if that's the state the containers are told to be in, or the content will be justified if you're on mobile.

The problem is, once content is added to these containers, whether it be using `.load()` to take it from a different document where it is being stored, or `.append()`, it is not taking on these properties.

I've made a fiddle to demonstrate [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4hLc8hg0/2/). Unfortunately, I can't demonstrate the `.load()` function due to only being able to use it on pages from the same domain ([at least that's what the jQuery documentation tells me](http://api.jquery.com/load/)), but you can still see exactly what I'm talking about from the `.append()` side of things.

In short;

Images in DOM initially work
[image]
Images appended / loaded into DOM do not
[image]
When mixing (some elements initial, some elements appended), this still holds true for the images placed in each of their separate ways.
[image]

If you examine the source of the mixture of initial/loaded, all elements look the same. The first 2 imgs here are the ones with proper word-spacing, while the rest do not have it.

[image]

Comment: when you use the load function to append the div, what is the DOM structure on that new file that is loaded. Maybe the style is not applied because  maybe ".projectPagePieces img"  does not exist in the new DOM?

Comment: @Sai correct me if I'm wrong, but `.projectPagePieces img` should address all objects of type `img` within `.projectPagePieces`, should it not? When it loads the content from the other page, it takes all the content from the div i tell it to and puts it into `.projectPagePieces`, which in this case, is all images. In the ends, `.projectPagePieces` looks identical whether it was created using images in the DOM initially, or whether they were loaded/appended.

Comment: Without looking at the code, I'm making an assumption that you have spaces in your code (or line breaks), and when something gets appended, it doesn't try to format the code for legibility, so instead of showing up as `<img />  <!-- line break that creates an inherent space --> <img />`, it renders it as `<img/><img/>`. When you load it, try appending `$(el).append($img + '&nbsp;');` or something similar.

Comment: Inline-block elements considers whitespaces and those whitespaces takes word spacing 25px while the appended images has no whitespaces.

Comment: To justify @anpsmn, take a [look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/4hLc8hg0/6/)

Comment: @Chad @anpsmn @LShetty This makes a lot of sense! Just tested it in reverse (by adding &nbsp; in-between each of the elements to be appended) and it fixed the spacing! However, I just tried adding &nbsp; after each `<img>` tag in the document to be loaded (on my actual site), and it didn't work. Is the `.load()` function trimming non-breaking spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add some spaces between the images when appending them it will treat the images like "words" and apply the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

The word-spacing property increases or decreases the white space between words. It's not good for the image. Below should be fine for you:

```
.projectPagePieces {
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    line-height: 0;
}
.projectPagePieces img {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```